# Get MSAccess version used to create MDB file

Tags: database, ms-access

I am looking for a way to get the version of MSAccess that was used to create a MDB file.

Any (tools, .bat, c#) suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I stumbled on (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/07/how-can-i-determine-which-version-of-access-was-used-to-create-a-database.aspx) link. With what has been explained, one could create a small executable which can give the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From VBA code, you could inspect the `FileFormat` property to determine the format version of your MDB file.  It will return a value from the `Access.AcFileFormat` class.

I used this in the Immediate window with an MDB created as Access 2002-2003 format.

```
? CurrentProject.FileFormat = acFileFormatAccess2002 
True
```

Notice however that doesn't say anything about the version of Access which was used to create the MDB.  I created it using Access 2007:

```
? Access.Version
12.0
```

As far as I'm aware, the version of Access used to create an MDB does not get stored anywhere within the MDB file.  And you could create an MDB by another method, such as with VBScript, which doesn't require an Access application instance to be running or even require Access to be installed.

Perhaps if you give us more information about why you want to know which Access version was used to create your MDB, someone can offer a workaround.